# Async call with fetch not waiting to done and going right away to the then

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I am trying to sequence the run of couple of functions one after the other.

The code below calculates correctly the pages but does not return anything to its caller.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function getNumberOfPages(url) {

    const pageUrl = url + "1";
    rp(pageUrl)
    .then(function(html) {
        return fetch(pageUrl)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            const entriesPerPage = 20;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let totalEntries = $(".Aa").first().text()
            let pagesNumber = Math.ceil(totalEntries / entriesPerPage);
            return pagesNumber;
            })
        })
}
```

Actually, the caller enters right away in B) and the console log is "Number pages: undefined".

```
function loadAllFeedbacks(url) {

    getNumberOfPages(url)
    // A) Get first the pages number
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Number pages: " + result);
    })
    // B) Executes this next
    .then(() => {
        rp(url)
```

I can't figure out why. It seems that I should do something with the fetch but don't know how.

Also wondering if there is any point to use `rp` and `fetch` together, seems one only suffices.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getNumberOfPages` gets to the end without returning anything, so it returns a promise that resolves as `undefined`.

You need to explicitly return something.

```
async function getNumberOfPages(url) {
    const pageUrl = url + "1";
    return rp(pageUrl)
    // etc
```

Now, however, you are returning a promise without using `await` at any point. So using the `async` keyword is pointless.

```
function getNumberOfPages(url) {
    const pageUrl = url + "1";
    return rp(pageUrl)
    // etc
```

Or you could rewrite the function to make use of `await`

```
async function getNumberOfPages(url) {
    const pageUrl = url + "1";
    const value_never_used = await rp(pageUrl);
    const response = await fetch(pageUrl);
    const html = await response.text();
    const entriesPerPage = 20;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    let totalEntries = $(".Aa").first().text();
    let pagesNumber = Math.ceil(totalEntries / entriesPerPage);
    return pagesNumber;
}
```

There's no point in using `request-promise` **and** `node-fetch`, hence `value_never_used`

Comment: Thank you so much! I had taken your first feedback and fixed my code with it, but definitely your second part is even more useful. Thanks also for having taken the time to explain and rewrite, cheers!